# TYPO3 : subparts not found?

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to modify a template in TYPO3 and I can modify some parts of the page, but not some other parts that are 1 level deeper. For example :

**HTML**

```
<body>
...
<div class="wrapper">
   ...
   <div id="content-right">
      <div id="colRight">
         <div id="metaNav"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
...
</body>
```

**Typoscript**

```
page.10.subparts {
  colRight = HMENU
  colRight.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  colRight.special.value = 6, 7, 8, 9
  colRight.1 = TMENU
  colRight.1 {
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      allWrap = <li>|</li>
    }
  }
}
```

But if I change `colRight` with `metaNav` (because this is where we want the links so we can place other contents in `colRight`), nothing happens; no content is displayed. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by changing `colRight` with `megaNav`? How is this templated with `automaketemplate` or common `subparts`?

Comment: oops, error on my part :) fixed. I need the content to be put in `<div id="metaNav"></div>` and not in it's parent, but it does not work for some reason with the given HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have it mapped to `#colRight` and have problem with mapping it to its child `div` you can just add a HTML markup to element's `wrap`:

```
page.10.subparts {
  colRight = HMENU
  colRight.wrap = <div id="metaNav"><ul>|</ul></div>
  // etc...      
}
```

With rule #1: *In TS every way is the **best** solution to get immediate results :)*

**edit**

if you need to render many different elements under one HTML tag, you can also use `COA` element to span them:

```
page.10.subparts {
  colRight = COA
  colRight {
      10 = HMENU
      10 {
          wrap = <div id="metaNav"><ul>|</ul></div>
          // etc...
      }

      20 = TEXT
      20 {
          value = my text in #colRight right after #metaNav
          wrap = <div class="containerAfterMetsNav">|</div>
      }

  }


}
```

Comment: yes, but if the template has already content in `colRight`, how would I go and *not* overwrite it with this code?

Comment: If you're mapping the whole `colRight` you need to use COA to render other content in the same HTML container. Give me some time, I'll post an edit to my answer

Comment: but... what is the problem with simply changing `colRight` with `metaNav` in my own source? Why doesn't it work? I'm utterly curious.

Comment: Yanick, I don't know, there are many possibilities, ie. if you mapped `#colRight` before, somewhere... then  the `#metaNav` will be unavailable as `colRight` defines its own 'body' (and do not care anymore about elements which where initially placed inside). I'm pretty sure, that it can be solved with detailed preview of the TypoScript, however with no full overview I can only guess. In meantime it's late night in Europe, so I will answer any your other questions by _my_ morning (in about 8hrs). I hope you'll find the solution soon. greetings.

Comment: I did upvote your answer, but I'd like to be able to just assign an empty element wherever in my DOM tree it can be. Typoscript *may* be flexible, but I'm not personally fond of it.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that some template did set `colRight` to some value (at the wrong place too) and I moved the portion of that script at the proper place and now I can assign to `metaNav` just find. Thank you for the explanation.